# Can't Execute .desktop File

Tags: launcher, java, minecraft

I'm new to ubuntu and linux...
I'm trying to make a minecraft launcher .desktop file, and when I execute it, it says me:
"There was an error launching the application"
My code is:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Minecraft
GenericName=PlayMinecraft
Comment=Game
Exec="/usr/bin/java -jar ~/Desktop/Minecraft.jar"
Icon=/usr/share/icons/icon.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

Can anybody help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `~/Desktop` to `/home/YOURUSERNAME`,

Before: 
`Exec=/usr/bin/java -jar ~/Desktop/Minecraft.jar`

After: `Exec=/usr/bin/java -jar /home/YOURUSERNAME/Desktop/Minecraft.jar`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I still get the same error...

Comment: Oh, sorry, I am so noob... I just remove the quotes from the Exec, and it's worked....

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `Path=/home/YOURUSERNAME/Desktop` to it, that's what made it work for me.

Comment: I'd give you a +1 for your answer. But the question is from a newbie and needs more handholding. Make an example. What is the "parent" of a path? How can he find this path?

Comment: parent_path in the noobie example above would be : /home/YOURUSERNAME/Desktop

Comment: Well then, don't answer as a comment. Instead click the edit link below your answer an update it accordingly.